# Separate internet router from LAN wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, router, home-networking, lan

I have a Linksys WRT54GL router running Tomato that I've been happy with for quite a while. I just purchased a TP-Link WDR3600 a/b/g/n + 4-port Gigabit ethernet router for better LAN throughput, and while it seems like a great performer so far, I'm quite disappointed with the factory firmware. Worse, even though it's advertized as "DD-WRT ready" it doesn't look like it's currently supported by any of the major open firmwares.

So I'm thinking about keeping the Linksys as my internet router, turning off its wifi, and using the TP-Link only for wifi connectivity. My reasoning is that my internet is only 10Mbps max anyway (which is fine for me), so the 100Mbps bottleneck shouldn't make a difference, right?

Are there any other pitfalls to this technique I'm not considering? I have a decent grasp on networking but am not familiar with "real-world" ramifications such as latency etc. FWIW I would then move the cable modem and Linksys physically farther from the TP-Link to keep them out of the way.

As far as setup, as long as the Linksys is still set as the DHCP server and gateway, and I turn off all routing features on the TP-Link, I can just connect the latter to one of the LAN ports on the former right? Then any wireless clients will just contact the Linksys to get their DHCP lease?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone comes across a similar situation, I tried this out and was indeed able to get it working as desired. Haven't noticed any slowdown so far. I should specify that I connected the two routers from one LAN port to another, through a gigabit switch I already had, though I probably could have used a crossover cable to link them directly.